# Style weeks using the Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: css, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using the [bootstrap datepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and suppose I wish to apply styles to the calendar that appear when the calendar opens:

1. Highlight 3/1/17 3/7/17 red
2. Highlight 3/9/17 3/17/17 blue

How can I use CSS to do this? Is there a feature in the API that allows for this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct API for this feature, but you can use option [`debug: true`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#debug) to inspect component HTML.

One way to target a specific day is using a CSS selector based on `data-day` attribute value, for example: `[data-day="03/01/2017"]`. Here a full live example:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  debug: true
});
```

```css
[data-day="03/01/2017"], [data-day="03/07/2017"]{
  background-color: red;
}

[data-day="03/09/2017"], [data-day="03/17/2017"]{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37528759/4131048) you can find a similar example.