# Showing custom colors to specified dates in a bootstrap datetime picker

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

In my `Java Spring MVC Web Application,` I am trying to use a `bootstrap DateTime picker`. I use bootstrap version `3.3.6`. I have added the DateTime picker using the following:
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#inline.
I am initializing the picker as follows:

```
$('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        inline: true
});

<div style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div id="datetimepicker12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using the picker to select a date and add some content for the selected date using my application. Now I want to show the dates for which contents are added in one color and the rest in another. So I am trying to show certain dates in the datetime picker with one color and the remaining dates with another. I am also trying dynamically control this. I will be passing the dates that are to be highlighted and I want those to be displayed with a specified color.

I have been searching for something similar, but could not find any help. Is there any way I can achieve this.

Comment: There is no direct API for this feature, but have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42380550/4131048) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37534168/4131048) to see some examples of customizing component appearance using CSS and [data attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

Recently I am working in a project that needs to implement some inline datepicker and i face same issue how to get the value from inline datepicker then i found the solution.
add this line on your event where you want to get the value.

```
var dat = $('#datetimepicker12').data("DateTimePicker").date();
alert(dat);
```